# setValue in formArray angular 8 and show ui

Tags: html, angular

I want show initial data in my formArray
i can set value and show value in console log but dont show this data in the ui form

```
 ngOnInit() {
  this.getCertificate(this.id);
  this.assessmentForm = this.fb.group({
   certificateArray: this.fb.array([ this.createItem() ]),
  });
 }
 createItem(): FormGroup {
   return this.fb.group({
     confirm: '',
     score: '',
     description: ''
   });
 }

 getCertificate(id) {
   this.certificateList = [];
   this.UsersRegisterService.getCertificate(id).subscribe((res: any[]) => {
     this.certificateList = res;
     var index=0;
     this.certificateList.forEach(element => {

       this.AssessmentService.getCertificateAssessment(element.id.value).subscribe((res: any[]) => {
    if(res!=null){
      this.certificateArray.at(index).setValue(
         { confirm: res['confirm'], score: res['score']['value'],description:res['description']});    
       console.log( this.assessmentForm['controls'].certificateArray['controls'][index]['controls'].score.value);
     }
    });
    index++;
  });
});
}
```

i set value this method

```
this.certificateArray.at(index).setValue(
   { confirm: res['confirm'], score: res['score']})
```

please help me how can i show this value in the Ui form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refactor your code a little bit, right now you have a shadowed name `res`. I would log responses from each call to `getCertificateAssessment` to make sure you're getting what you expect:

```
  getCertificate(id) {
    this.certificateList = []; // this should be set at the top of your component
    this.UsersRegisterService.getCertificate(id).pipe(
      catchError(err => {
        console.log('get cert error', err);
        return [];
      })
    ).subscribe((list) => {
      this.certificateList = list;
      this.certificateList.forEach((element, i) => {
        this.AssessmentService.getCertificateAssessment(element.id.value).pipe(
        catchError(err => {
          console.log('get assessment error', err);
          return null;
        })
      ).subscribe((res) => {
          if (res) {
            console.log('res', i, res); // be sure of response
            this.certificateArray.at(i).setValue({
              confirm: res.confirm,
              score: res.score.value,
              description: res.description
            });
          } else {
            console.log('no res!');
          }
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

Chris makes a good point about piping but I'm guessing these service calls are http requests so they complete just like a promise.

I also added `catchError` to catch errors with the service calls.

Plus you are having to make a call for each assessment which makes for a lot of calls. Maybe refactor your backend to make it 1 call?

**If you refactored** the endpoint for `getCertficateAssessment` to accept an array of values and return an array of responses, you could do this:

```
    this.UsersRegisterService.getCertificate(id).pipe(
      switchMap(list => this.AssessmentService.getCertificateAssessment(list.map(l => l.id.value)))
    );
```

You would need to create an id for each assessment so you could assign them.

Answer (score 1):

Use `patchValue`

```
this.certificateArray.at(index).patchValue(res);
```

Note that you would never subscribe inside a subscription, and even less often (never never) subscribe in a forEach. `pipe` the data instead.

Comment: i used patchValue but this function is like setValue!! changed value in console log but dont show in Form

Comment: Yeah, that's why I added the edit to the question - might be that change detection simply doesn't run correctly since your subscription inside a forEach inside a subscription will cause problems. @kamal

Comment: tnx for answer but i want give data in subscrib and subcrib is a async function